# What is simpler? REST or SOAP in 11g?

Tags: rest, soap, oracle11g

I've read a little about REST and SOAP technologies and I understand REST is simpler than SOAP, but what about working with REST in Oracle 11g?
Oracle 11g uses his framework to handle the SOAP's complexity.
So, What would it be simpler using 11g, REST and his simplicity or SOAP with the framework's help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With modern Oracle, you can take your pick, REST or SOAP, or side-by-side.

Using APEX it is pretty easy to get up and running.

Otherwise, use your app server of choice (Java - including Oracle App Server, .NET, etc.)

Choosing REST vs SOAP is really a question based on several factors: your requirements, your business, your development environment, whether you expose services to third parties.

So for your actual question, you may feel no difference in simplicity, if you use the right tools. But SOAP provides more capability in the long-haul (WCF, security, different transports, data contracts), and the use of WSDL will accelerate integration as it can be more plug-and-play using IDEs like Visual Studio.

The only reason I'd choose REST is if I were coding things by hand. Otherwise, SOAP is my choice.